# javascript/google maps: Why does it matter where I initialize my map (inside vs outside function)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Short summary: When I move my map declaration out of the function that initializes markers and places them on my google maps, my map fails and doesn't have any markers at all. Why does it matter where I declare my map?

Longer version: I want to write a general function to place all latitudes and longitudes from two arrays onto a google maps. I am using the following:

```
 var lat_array = <?php echo $slat.";"; ?>
 var lon_array = <?php echo $slon.";"; ?>
 var markers = []

 function init_map(map) {

     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 14,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
     });

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>);

     bounds.extend(myLatLng);

     var pinColor = "009ACD";
     var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,


                                                new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                                                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                                new google.maps.Point(10, 34));



     for(var ii =0; ii<lat_array.length; ii++)
     {
         marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_array[ii], lon_array[ii]),
             icon: pinImage
         });

         markers.push(marker2)
             myNewLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_array[ii], lon_array[ii]);
         bounds.extend(myNewLatLng);
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

 }


 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

This works fine. Now I want to modify the function to make it more general by declaring the map outside init_map and passing it to init_map so that I can make many different maps on the same page more easily. However when I modify the code by moving the map declaration outside the function like so:

```
 var myOptions = {
             zoom: 14,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

     function init_map(map) {
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
         });
...
```

My code now fails. I get this error in my JS console, which I don't know how to interpret:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama
```

None of these terms appear in my code, so I don't know how to interpret them. In addition to that error, now I have a map with no pins.

What's wrong with moving the map declaration out of my function? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 14,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    function init_map(map) {
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
    });
```

In the first example, you are making the options and map variable. However, you are clobbering your `map` argument in the function and replacing it with the one pointing to the map-canvas element.

When you move that declaration out of the function body, you are no longer clobbering the map argument; you are relying on it to be a valid map.

Perhaps something like

```
function init_map(map) {
   if (!map) {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
   }
   ...
```

Comment: given technical terms like hoist and splat, it might actually be unknowable